# Check if string that must be just numbers has characters

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, typescript

I have a input for phone number, and its type is not number is text, and I want to check if the input has characters to validate it as wrong, I have set it like that because I put a format to the input like 123-123-1234
here is my input

```
<input (keyup)="format()" (change)="format()" maxlength="12" inputmode="numeric" type='text' class="input" formControlName="celular" id="celular" name="celular">
```

Here is my ts where I set the format

```
  format(){
    $('#celular').val($('#celular').val().replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)$/, "$1-$2-$3"));
  }
```

so what I want to do, is to know if the value of my input has characters from aA-zZ and some specials characters that are not -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution

```
var b = /[a-z A-Z]/
var a = '123a'
b.test(a)
```

this gives true or false depending if the var a has any character from a-z and A-Z

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from google i found this:

```
Regex phoneRegex =
    new Regex(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$");

if (phoneRegex.IsMatch(subjectString)) {
    string formattedPhoneNumber =
        phoneRegex.Replace(subjectString, "($1) $2-$3");
} else {
    // Invalid phone number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use html regex pattern for validating input fields

Example:

Format used in this example is 123-123-1234

```html
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone Number in format (123-123-1234)" pattern="^\d{3}[-]\d{3}[-]\d{4}$" title="Invalid input" size="50" />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I have seen this, but I was told to make it automatically, that the input introduces de - and that it is numeric and check if the value has any character, but I finally found it, that was this
var b = /[a-z A-Z]/
var a = '123a'
b.test(a)
that works to see if the string has any character